# Declaring a Property with Type Constraint in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I need to create a custom fields framework in my app. I defined a protocol for the fields called `FieldType` and extended with it `UITextField` and `UIButton` to be different types of fields.

Now I want to create a container view for the fields so I want the container to be able to refer to its field elements as both `UIView`s and `FieldType`s, and I'm wondering if there's a concise way to define the type of elements it receives to be a specific `UIView` that implements the `FieldType` protocol?

I can have `FieldContainerView` accept `UIView`s or `FieldType`s and check manually that it also matches the other with a `guard` statement, but it feels a bit cumbersome.

I tried 2 approaches:

### 1) Define a Custom Intermediary `FieldViewType`

The idea is to have `FieldViewType` extend `UIView` directly with `FieldType` so it might be useful as a general case for `UITextField: FieldType` and `UIButton: FieldType`. But as this code sample clearly shows, this does not work.

```
protocol FieldType {
  var showError: Bool { get set }
  var isEmpty: Bool { get set }
}

class CustomTextField: UITextField, FieldType {}
class CustomButtonField: UIButton, FieldType {}

let textField = CustomTextField()
textField is UIView       // True
textField is FieldType    // True

let buttonField = CustomButtonField()
buttonField is UIView     // True
buttonField is FieldType  // True

class FieldView: UIView, FieldProtocol {}

let field = FieldView()
field is UIView           // True
field is FieldProtocol    // True

textField is FieldView    // False
buttonField is FieldView  // False
```

### 2) Use Generics

I can define a generic type that matches the requirements like so `<FieldViewType: UIView where FieldViewType: FieldType>`, but I don't see where to use to best solve my problem. If I define it at the class level

```
class FieldContainerView<FieldViewType: UIView where FieldViewType: FieldType>: UIView {
  var fields = [FieldViewType]()
  func addField(FieldViewType: field) {
    fields.append(field)
  }
}
```

I need to declare the container class once for each field type I'll want to use and won't be able to use 2 field types in the same container.

The other option is to define type constraint at the function level with `addField`

```
class FieldContainerView: UIView {
  var fields = [UIView]()
  func addField<FieldViewType: UIView where FieldViewType: FieldType>(FieldViewType: field) {
    fields.append(field)
  }
}
```

and then cast each element in `fields` to `FieldType` when necessary and I'll know the cast will always work because `addField` is the only way to add elements to the container. But this also feels too cumbersome.

It feels like the best way around this would have been to be able to define `FieldViewType` with a `typealias`, but this doesn't seem to be supported. Or have `UIView` be defined with a protocol so it could be mixed better, but UIKit isn't constructed in this manner.

Comment: Is `FieldType` really an empty protocol?  If not, what is actually in it?  Can you post the *actual* `FieldType` protocol?

Comment: Added the implementation. There might other stuff in it down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that at the moment there's no way to create a type constraint in property declarations. I don't know why, but I don't know anything about language implementations.

I went for a workaround where `FieldType` also has a `view: UIView` property with a default implementation.

The new `FieldType` declaration:

```
protocol FieldType {
  var showError: Bool { get set }
  var isEmpty: Bool { get set }
  var view: UIView { get }
}

extension FieldType where Self: UIView {
  var view: UIView {
    return self
  }
}
```

This way it doesn't matter from which class in the UIKit hierarchy you inherited before conforming to the `FieldType` protocol, as long as you have `UIView` somewhere as your super class, you'll have an accessibly `view` property.

This feels like a workaround, but at least it saves dual-declarations for collections that need both the `FieldType` and the `UIView` properties of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change this line:
class FieldView: UIView, FieldProtocol {}

To this:
class FieldView: UIView, FieldType {}